# Can a non-EU citizen enter EU countries using a Bulgarian D visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, schengen-visas, lebanese-citizens

I am Lebanese, and I have a passport valid until 2020. I have a Bulgarian national visa D. Can I travel in EU countries without a Schengen visa?

Comment: You cannot travel to the UK https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/lebanon/tourism/no

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines, you can travel to Croatia, Cyprus and Romania on a Bulgarian D visa, but not to Schengen countries, the UK or Ireland. For those, you need separate visas unless holding a family member residence card.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have a sister living in Austria and she holds a resident card there, how she can help me to visit her ?

Comment: @Heissam She cannot; it's up to you to convince the Austrian embassy that you're a bona fide visitor and will return to Bulgaria. Do bring a notarised letter from her explaining the dates and purpose of your trip.